# fmaxf returns huge number?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

[image]
I think that I don't see some obvious mistake, but what can be possibly wrong here? I tried fmaxd and fmaxl and it did not work as well.

Comment: you are seeing the default value __before__ the actual evaluation happens.

Comment: @holex wait a second, i will check this

Comment: @Bathsheba, if that is the solution for the problem, I will be happy to do so.

Comment: @holex you are right! You can post your comment as an answer, i will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are seeing the default value of the `maximumPointSize` here **before** the actual evaluation happens.